# Convert dictionary to datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset

Tags: python, dataset, data-preprocessing, huggingface-datasets, stable-diffusion

I'm trying to use the [Pokemon finetuning notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/LambdaLabsML/examples/blob/main/stable-diffusion-finetuning/pokemon_finetune.ipynb), which uses the [Pokemon BLIP captions dataset](https://huggingface.co/datasets/lambdalabs/pokemon-blip-captions); see the [GitHub](https://github.com/LambdaLabsML/examples/tree/main/stable-diffusion-finetuning) from the [Lambda Labs examples repo](https://github.com/LambdaLabsML/examples); the training code is in the [justinpinkney/stable-diffusion](https://github.com/justinpinkney/stable-diffusion) code base. I want to fine-tune Stable Diffusion on the [MuMu dataset](https://zenodo.org/record/7399400) of album covers.

I have a (N, 512, 512, 3) numpy array of images and a (N) list of caption strings. The original code base works with a <class 'datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset'> object, so I attempt to convert my dataset to this format using [datasets.Dataset.from_dict()](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v1.1.1/package_reference/main_classes.html#datasets.Dataset.from_dict) within hf_dataset() in [ldm/data/simple.py](https://github.com/justinpinkney/stable-diffusion/blob/main/ldm/data/simple.py):

```
img_dict = {}
for i in range(len(img_tensor)):
    img_dict[i] = { 'image': img_tensor[i], 'text': img_captions[i] }
from datasets.Dataset import from_dict
ds = from_dict(img_dict)
```

This produces a huge error traceback ending in:

```
File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 100, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: arrays to be concatenated must be identically typed, but list<item: list<item: uint8>> and string were encountered.
```

I think the problem is that img_tensor[i] is a 2D array (a list of lists of uint8 entries) and img_captions[i]  is a string. **How can I convert my data to a datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset object?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, wasn't reading the documentation carefully enough. I have a dictionary of integer keys with dictionary values, but I need "a mapping of strings to Arrays or Python lists" as per [the documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v1.1.1/package_reference/main_classes.html#datasets.Dataset.from_dict). Here's a toy example:

```
img_tensor = np.zeros((100, 512, 512, 3))
captions = []
for i in range(100):
  captions.append('hello')
captioned_imgs = {
    'images': img_tensor,
    'text': captions
}
from datasets import Dataset
out = Dataset.from_dict(captioned_imgs)
print(type(out))
```

Output: <class 'datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset'>